# How to get ''git show-branch" from Gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm looking after a way to get the equivalent of [`git show-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch) from Gitlab API, in order to avoid of checkouting my repos when I don't need sources, but branch history...

The functionnality does not seems to exist, do you know a way to get around this lack ?

Comment: The link you posted points to a local file in your computer...

Comment: @OldFart corrected, thanks !